# Django migration fails for modules with a dash in the name

Tags: django, module, migration, pip

This is the INSTALLED_APPS from my module:

```
    # Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'django.contrib.sitemaps',
'django.contrib.sites',
'django.contrib.flatpages',
'djangocms_admin_style',
'django.contrib.admin',
'djangocms_text_ckeditor',
'djangocms_link',
'contact',
...
```

When I run my migrations I get an error:
ImportError djangocms_admin_style: No module named djangocms_admin_style.

If i run pip freeze the app is installed:
djangocms-admin-style (with hyphen)

So how can I correct this?

Comment: try to change djangocms_admin_style to djangocms-admin-style in your INSTALLED_APPS

Comment: Are you using a virtualenv? If so, is it activated when you run your app?

Comment: If i change djangocms_admin_style to djangocms-admin_style and I want to run my app, then he gives the error:
ImportError: No module named djangocms-admin-style

I'm using a virtualenv yes and it's activated.

Answer (score 8):

I did

> pip install djangocms_admin_style

in my virtualenv.

And then did this in my settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
'djangocms_admin_style',
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'stacko',
```

)

After this when I ran `python manage.py makemigrations`, it worked without errors

SO maybe you haven't done

> pip install djangocms_admin_style

Comment: I used Django 1.6.5, so makemigrations doesn't work.
In my INSTALLED_APPS is also djangocms_admin_style.

Comment: But in the question you said that you got this error while running migrations.So what command were you running?

Comment: I was running python manage.py migrate
In 1.6.5 the makemigrations command doesn't exists yet

Comment: Well, I could run the migrate command successfully as well! Try this: uninstall djangocms_admin_style and then install again using pip .Also try putting 'djangocms_admin_style' at the top of INSTALLED_APPS, as maybe, somewhere in your INSTALLED_APPS list, something is overriding or conflicting with 'djangocms_admin_style'. Naive attempts at debugging but then can't understand the root cause.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

Check what version of Python you have installed and run

```
python(version) manage.py makemigrations
```